# Improve or replace a complex, slow SQL cursor with set statements

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I have a cursor that uses two tables.  The logic behind it is for travelling routes for a business application.  Lets say you have four destinations - City A, City B, City C and City D.  Sometimes you drive from A to B and back again.  But other times you drive from A to B to C to D and then back to A - this would be called a Rounder.

In the business application out and back (back and forth from A to B) is priced differently then if you did a Rounder.  In one table there are the routes - A to B , C to D etc.  In the other table there is the costing estimates.  If they just went A to B - use this price, for a Rounder use this price.

Call it a Route table, with the routes driven, and a Costing table, with the prices for all the routes and rounders.

I need to loop through all the trips and look to see if there is a matching '2nd half' of a Rounder.  They aren't necessarily in order - they might go C to D then A to B - but this still counts as a Rounder.  Or they might go A to B, X to Y, then C to D.  The A to B and the subsequent C to D count as a Rounder.

The way I do is to start with the first row in the Route table and loop through the table see if any of the rows match with the 2nd half of a Rounder.  If there is no match then, it is just a simple out and back.  I use a cursor to do this - and it is SLOW - but I can't think of any way to turn this into a set based SQL statement.

Here's my code if you are up for a re-write to remove a cursor challenge.....

```
 create table #RouteLegs (
   RowNbr int,
   RouteID varchar(20) INDEX IDX_RouteID NONCLUSTERED,
   TripDate datetime INDEX IDX_TripDate CLUSTERED,
   WaybillNbr varchar(16) INDEX IDX_WaybillNbr NONCLUSTERED,
   MatchedRowNbr int,
   CostingModelID int,
   Legs varchar(5),
   RounderCode varchar(100)
)

insert into #RouteLegs
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by actual.TripDate) as RowNbr, 
   actual.RouteID,
   cast(actual.TripDate as date) as trip_date,
   actual.Waybill_Number,
   0, 0, '', ''
from staging.RouteSoureTable


declare @NbrMatches int,
      @CurrRouteID varchar(20),
      @CurrRowNbr int,
      @CurrTripDate datetime,
      @CurrWaybillNbr varchar(16),
      @MatchRouteID varchar(20),
      @MatchRowNbr int,
      @MatchTripDate datetime,
      @CostingModelID int,
      @MatchFound int = 0,
      @FrontLegs varchar(10),
      @BackLegs varchar(10)

declare csrRouteLeg cursor for
select RouteID, RowNbr, TripDate, WaybillNbr 
from #RouteLegs 
order by RowNbr

open csrRouteLeg

fetch next from csrRouteLeg 
into @CurrRouteID, @CurrRowNbr, @CurrTripDate, @CurrWaybillNbr

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
   -- print 'begin matching' + cast(@CurrRowNbr as varchar(10)) 
   --reset flag and start looking
   set @MatchFound = 0

   --check if already matched to another route leg
   select @MatchFound = MatchedRowNbr from #RouteLegs where RowNbr = @CurrRowNbr

   if @MatchFound = 0 
   begin

      if @MatchFound = 0 
      begin 

         --otherwise find the correct costing model baased on matching backhauls   
         declare csrFindMatch cursor for
         select RouteID, RowNbr, TripDate 
         from #RouteLegs
         where RowNbr <> @CurrRowNbr
            and MatchedRowNbr = 0
         order by RowNbr

        -- print 'new matching recordset'
         open csrFindMatch

         fetch next from csrFindMatch 
         into @MatchRouteID, @MatchRowNbr, @MatchTripDate

         while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
         begin    
            --this is a front haul with a matching backhaul
            --print 'DATEDIFF ' + CAST( ABS(DATEDIFF(D,@CurrTripDate,@MatchTripDate)) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' row ' + cast(@MatchRowNbr as varchar(20))
            if @MatchFound = 0 AND ABS(DATEDIFF(D,@CurrTripDate,@MatchTripDate)) < @DayGapBetweenBackHaul
            begin
                select @MatchFound = coalesce(max(CostingModelID), 0) 
                   from xref_Costing_withBH xr
                   inner join DimCosting dim
                      on xr.CostingModelID = dim.CostingModelCode 
                   where FirstLegRouteCode = @CurrRouteID and BackLegRouteCode = @MatchRouteID
                      --and @CurrTripDate between dim.CostingModelEffectiveDate and dim.CostingModelExpiryDate

                select @FrontLegs = max([Costing Model Leg]), @BackLegs = max([BH Legs]) from [staging].[operations_file_CostingModelRouteLinkage] where [Costing Model #] = @MatchFound

                if @MatchFound > 0
                begin
                    --print 'Front - ' + cast(@CurrRouteID as varchar(20)) + ' Back - ' + cast( @MatchRouteID as varchar(20)) + ' Row - ' + cast(@CurrRowNbr as varchar(20)) +  ' front haul with a matching backhaul'
                    set @RounderCode = 'Backhaul-' + ltrim(rtrim(cast(@AssetCode as varchar(20)))) + '-' + cast(@MatchFound as varchar(20))  + '-' + cast(@BatchID as varchar(20))+ '-' + cast(@CurrRowNbr as varchar(20))
                    update  #RouteLegs
                     set MatchedRowNbr = @MatchRowNbr,
                         Legs = @FrontLegs,
                         CostingModelID = @MatchFound,
                         RounderCode = @RounderCode

                      where RowNbr = @CurrRowNbr

                    update  #RouteLegs
                     set MatchedRowNbr = @CurrRowNbr,
                         Legs = @BackLegs,
                         CostingModelID = @MatchFound,
                         RounderCode = @RounderCode

                      where RowNbr = @MatchRowNbr

                    -- select * from #RouteLegs
                    --print 'front haul updated'
                end
                else
                   --this could be a back haul with a matching front haul - but first check this row hasn't been matched in a previous loop
                   select @MatchFound = COALESCE(MatchedRowNbr, 0) from #RouteLegs where RowNbr = @CurrRowNbr

                   if @MatchFound = 0 
                   begin 
                      select @MatchFound = coalesce(max(CostingModelID) , 0) 
                         from xref_Costing_withBH xr
                         inner join DimCosting dim
                            on xr.CostingModelID = dim.CostingModelCode 
                         where FirstLegRouteCode = @MatchRouteID and BackLegRouteCode = @CurrRouteID
                            --and @CurrTripDate between dim.CostingModelEffectiveDate and dim.CostingModelExpiryDate

                      select @FrontLegs = max([Costing Model Leg]), @BackLegs = max([BH Legs]) from [staging].[operations_file_CostingModelRouteLinkage] where [Costing Model #] = @MatchFound

                      if @MatchFound > 0 AND ABS(DATEDIFF(D,@CurrTripDate,@MatchTripDate)) < @DayGapBetweenBackHaul
                      begin
                         --print 'Front - ' + cast(@MatchRouteID as varchar(20)) + ' Back - ' + cast( @CurrRouteID as varchar(20)) + ' Row - ' + cast(@CurrRowNbr as varchar(20)) +  ' this is a back haul with a matching front haul'
                         set @RounderCode = 'Backhaul-' + ltrim(rtrim(cast(@AssetCode as varchar(20)))) + '-' + cast(@MatchFound as varchar(20))  + '-' + cast(@BatchID as varchar(20))+ '-' + cast(@CurrRowNbr as varchar(20))

                         update  #RouteLegs
                            set MatchedRowNbr = @MatchRowNbr,
                                Legs = @BackLegs,
                                CostingModelID = @MatchFound,
                                RounderCode = @RounderCode

                            where RowNbr = @CurrRowNbr

                         update  #RouteLegs
                            set MatchedRowNbr = @CurrRowNbr,
                                Legs = @FrontLegs,
                                CostingModelID = @MatchFound,
                                RounderCode = @RounderCode

                            where RowNbr = @MatchRowNbr

                            --select * from #RouteLegs                               
                            --print 'back  haul updated'

                      end
                   end
            end

            fetch next from csrFindMatch 
            into @MatchRouteID, @MatchRowNbr, @MatchTripDate          
         end

         close csrFindMatch
         deallocate csrFindMatch
      end


   fetch next from csrRouteLeg 
   into @CurrRouteID, @CurrRowNbr, @CurrTripDate, @CurrWaybillNbr
   end

   fetch next from csrRouteLeg 
   into @CurrRouteID, @CurrRowNbr, @CurrTripDate, @CurrWaybillNbr
end

close csrRouteLeg
deallocate csrRouteLeg
```

Comment: OUCH!!!! No wonder this is so slow!!! You have nested cursors. You have to change your mindset. You are thinking about what you need to do to each row. You need to start thinking about what you need to do each column. There is little to no chance anybody can give you a solid replacement here with nothing more than a wall of code. We would need tables and sample data at the very least. If this was a consulting situation I would estimate this at least 2-3 days. I can't speak for others but that is entirely too much work for an online forum.

Comment: you're right - the only reason I posted is because I am having troubles 're-thinking' it.  I am replacing a human logic process with sql....  What do you mean by looking at it 'by column'?

Comment: Try this article. It does a good explaining what "thinking in sets" means. http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-foundations-thinking-sets

Comment: @SeanLange , I'd quote it at 1-2 days, but charge 50% more, heh.

Comment: I would consider recursive CTE. How many "Legs" can one "Rounder" have?